# Proving $\mathrm{det}\, T = \mathrm{det}\, R\, \mathrm{det}\, S$ given $T: V\to V$ by $T{\bf x}=R{\bf w}_1+S{\bf w}_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations, determinant, direct-sum

I've been learning linear algebra and I came across this question that I don't know how to solve. The question begins by letting $W_1$ and $W_2$ be subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Suppose that $V=W_1 \oplus W_2$. Then, for any $x∈V$ we may express $x$ uniquely as $x=w_1+w_2$ where $w_1∈W_1$ and $w_2∈W_2$. Let $R: W_1 \to W_1$ and $S: W_2\to W_2$ be linear transformations and define the linear transformation$T = \mathrm{det}\, R\, \mathrm{det}\, S$ given $T: V\to V$ by $T{\bf x}=R{\bf w}_1+S{\bf w}_2$

The question asks to prove $\mathrm{det}\, T = \mathrm{det}\, R\, \mathrm{det}\, S$

If anyone could give some guidance or help solve this problem, I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, then
$$\det\pmatrix{A&0\\0&B}\ =\ \det A\cdot\det B\,.$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, do you mind commenting on the eigenvalues of $T$?

Comment: No I don't mind. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $R$ or $S$, it will be so for $T$ as well.

Comment: awesome! is there a certain property that makes it so?

Comment: Yes, that $V=W_1\oplus W_2$ which are both invariant under $T$. It's just set up by two independent transformations.